# Was the "Lensman" armor an example of powered armor?

Tags: armor, lensman-series

A recent question asked "[Which was the first sci-fi story to feature power armors for military use?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242900/which-was-the-first-sci-fi-story-to-feature-power-armors-for-military-use/)". In the end the answer accepted was "The Affair of the Brains" by Anthony Gilmore, published in 1932, but an obvious contender for the title is the "Lensman" series by E.E. "Doc" Smith. Indeed [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapons_in_science_fiction#Powered_armor_and_fighting_suits) notes:

> The idea of powered armor has appeared in a wide variety of fiction,
> beginning with E. E. Smith's Lensman series in 1937.

However another source, the [SF Encyclopedia](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/powered_armour), states:

> Space armour in E E Smith's Galactic Patrol (September 1937-February
> 1938 Astounding; 1950) and later Lensman books is sometimes cited as
> early powered armour; however, despite energy screens and Space Flight
> capability via inertialess drive, the key feature of augmenting the
> wearer's strength is never explicitly ascribed to Smith's armour.

So my question, distinct from the one I cite above is: **Is there enough evidence to conclude that the Lensman armor was powered or not?**

I would certainly say that the earliest appearances of the armor, in "Galactric Patrol" (1937) for example, were clearly not powered. But in "[Children of the Lens](https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/smithee-childrenofthelens/smithee-childrenofthelens-00-h.html)" (1947), the armor is described as:

> The Lensman landed, and made his way to Harkleroy’s inner office in
> what seemed to be an ordinary enough, if somewhat over-size, suit of
> light space-armor. But it was no more ordinary than it was light. It
> was a power-house, built of dureum a quarter of an inch thick.
> Kinnison was not walking in it; he was merely the engineer of a
> battery of two-thousand-horsepower motors. Unaided, he could not have
> lifted one leg of that armor off the ground.

Dureum is a metal alloy "incredibly massive, unbelievably tough, unimaginably hard". Indeed it is so heavy that the Lensman cannot walk unaided in it, and needs the assistance of powerful motors to even move a leg. To participate in the fist fights later, wouldn't that imply that the armor must have been powered to augment his arm strength? Admittedly this is not *explicitly* stated, but it seems a clear consequence of the armor's weight. Is there any more compelling evidence, either way, from Smith's books or comments?

Comment: It's possible that the armour evolved (became increasingly capable and powerful) over the course of the series in the same way as their ships and psychic abilities.  So in the earlier stories it may have been more like a heavy EVA suit while later it evolved into a fully self-propelled fighting suit à la *Starship Troopers*.

Comment: @DavidW So would you class the armor in the later stories as true powered armor?

Comment: Based on the quote you've given - that he could not have moved without assistance - I think it's incontrovertible.  It's definitely a suit (not, for example, a mini-mecha), that's described as armour and necessarily powered.  The only possible quibble is if the Lensmen are considered more "peace officers" rather than "military" but that's a pretty fine hair, considering the straight up battles they fight.